# Where should 1em be defined - when to use lengths in "em"

Tags: document-classes, lengths

The table in the document below looks as expected when using the `article` document class. With other document classes, the rules dissapear.

The reason seems to be that `booktabs` defines the with of the rules in units of `em` which is apparently not set in some documentclasses, e.g. `revtex4-1` (which I was using).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{revtex4-1} % 1em=0pt
%\documentclass{minimal}   % 1em=0pt
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{1em}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Light rule width:&\the\lightrulewidth\\ 
    \midrule
    Heavy rule width:&\the\heavyrulewidth\\ 
    \midrule
    Width of 1em:&\the\mylength \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Where *should* the `em` unit be defined? Is it the job of the class, font package or the document author? When should I avoid using lengths in units of `em`?

Comment: The `em` is a parameter from the font. It is not defined in a class.

Comment: And this actually a problem when for example the standard LaTeX2e kernel uses the `em` in its typesetting of the table of contents: for some font where this `em` is too small, `subsections` and even worse  `subsubsection` entries show an overlap between the entry number and the entry name.

Comment: @jfbu: the "standard classes" were designed with the cm fonts in mind.  they _happen_ to work with many other fonts, but one should in principal design layouts with a font in mind.  if some particular font's design doesn't work with the standard classes, it's the class that should change, not the font.  (and of course, you change a standard class by creating a new one that goes `\LoadClass{article}` (or whatever) and then patching the parameters as needed.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say `\setlength{\mylength}{1em}`, the real length stored in `\mylength` will depend on the font that is current at the time of the assignment.

Each font defines its own `em` unit; for instance it is 10pt for the usual Computer Modern Roman at 10pt; it is 19pt for `\huge` (which is Computer Modern Roman at 20.7pt).

If you say `\hspace{1em}`, the current size of the `em` is used. For some reasons (that I don't understand), the `revtex4-1` class doesn't issue the `\normalsize` and `\normalfont` commands, so in the preamble the current font is still the "null" one, which has all font parameters zero. Only at begin document the main document font is established.

Conversely the standard classes (not `minimal`) issue the command `\normalsize` after having defined it, so the `em` unit will have a value. Possibly not the one for the main document font, however: some font packages delay selecting the main font at begin document.

When to choose the `em` unit for setting a length? I recommend only some specific cases, that is, the lengths that should depend on the main font size. An important case is `\parindent`. Great typographers recommend that the normal paragraph indent should be 1em; if you want to ensure this and not rely on the LaTeX default (for the standard classes) of 15pt, then

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}
```

will do the right thing, provided this is issued after having loaded the font packages. Also other lengths could be set in terms of the main font's em: all those regarding list indentations, for instance, which shouldn't depend on the relative font size.

For "explicit" horizontal lengths, using `em` is recommendable, but one can also choose fractions of the column width: it mostly depends on the specific application.

---

**NOTE.** The behavior of `revtex4-1` is nonstandard and should be corrected, in my opinion. Some packages rely on a default em for setting their own defaults (which is a good guess in many cases). If you issue `\normalsize` before doing settings that involve the em, you'll get it. Having to issue `\normalsize` before loading `booktabs` is to be considered a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I have notified the REVTeX maintainers about the missing `\normalsize`. While this is nonstandard for a document class, do you consider not issuing `\normalsize` in the `booktabs` package prior to setting up rules in units of `em` to be a booktabs-bug?

Comment: @MartinHeller No; packages expect that the class issues `\normalsize`.

Answer (score 5):

The other documentclasses fail to select fonts on loading.  As the `em` unit is defined in terms of the current font this can be fixed by adding the command `\normalfont` before loading `booktabs` (and after any font packages that might be relevant), which expects `em` to be defined:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\normalfont
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{1em}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Light rule width:&\the\lightrulewidth\\ 
    \midrule
    Heavy rule width:&\the\heavyrulewidth\\ 
    \midrule
    Width of 1em:&\the\mylength \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

When using the `article` documentclass, you load `article.cls` which in turn loads `size10.clo` (for 10pt).  This `.clo` file includes the call `\normalsize` which in turn includes a `\selectfont` command, bringing the current font in to action.